# What is the upper bound for size of the code I can post on Code Review?

Tags: discussion, code-length

Suppose I'm writing a library and there are parts of it which I wish to be reviewed. What is the upper bound for size of the codebase (in characters, classes for example) which is considered to be acceptable to post on CR?